# Did Sic Mundus exist in some form in the Original World?

Tags: dark

In the third season of Dark, we learn that

> both Adam and Eva's worlds spawned from the destruction of the Original World when H.G. Tannhaus activated his time machine prototype in an attempt to go back in time and prevent the death of his son's family. This world is restored when Jonas and Martha travel to it and they themselves prevent the death of the Tannhaus' son's family thus removing the motive behind the activation of the time machine entirely.

Earlier on this very same season however, we also learn that Sic Mundus was actually established in the 19th century under a similar premise and by an Heinrich Tannhaus who was an ancestor of H.G Tannhaus. Bartosz mentions that the "old man Tannhaus" (referring to Heinrich's son) that Sic Mundus was a secret society that was created by Heinrich in an attempt to revert the death of his wife, but that by the time they arrived in the 19th century, old man Tannhaus was all that was left of it.

Now, I don't remember any time interference happening at anytime before Jonas arrived with Magnus, Franziska and Bartosz on the 19th century. Does this means that Sic Mundus did exist in the original world as well but disappeared in obscurity after old man Tannhaus died?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does Sic Mundus exist in the Original World? Yes.

Has it existed even before Adam in the Spawned Worlds? Yes.

> The Sic Mundus Secret Society dates back to the 19th Century in
> Winden. Founder Heinrich Tannhaus sought to overcome the laws of time
> and space and bring his wife Charlotte back from the dead. Tannhaus
> devoted his entire life to Sic Mundus, as did his son Gustav, who was
> the last remaining member of the group in 1888. Gustav was delighted
> when time travelers arrived in Winden. They carried on the group's
> tradition following Gustav's death.  In 1921, Adam is the leader of
> the Sic Mundus.

[-Dark | The Official Guide-](https://www.dark.netflix.io/en/event-timeline/sic-mundus-creatus-est)

As the source clearly states, Sic Mundus existed before Adam arrived, and the reason for its creation (bringing back Heinrich's dead wife) was not dependent on Adam or his world at all.

Therefore we can safely say it existed in the Original World.